# Interior point or not.

Tags: real-analysis

Is $0$ a interior point of the set $\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} ∪\{\frac{-1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}∪\{0\} $

I think it is not , as there is no irrationals in that set.

Is it enough to say?

What will happen if I go for subspace topology on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Is $0$ still not a interior?

Comment: $0$ does not even belong to this set !

Comment: Sorry,I edited.

Comment: Ok, so now, you should precise which topology you consider.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: It's the usual one.

Comment: @JohnDouma The reasoning is correct for the usual topology, but would be incorrect for some other topologies.

Comment: @Alearner That should be part of the question. Besides what is the topological space that you are working with?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I don't know about you, but when I was taking analysis, the question of which topology I am using would have blown my mind. I think it is pretty safe to assume we are in the land of epsilons and deltas.

Comment: @JohnDouma Pretty safe, yeah... until the day you arrive in a new land, and you are lost, if you are not prepared !

Comment: @John Douma real analysis just like a single part of topology, as if we define usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and on this whole real analysis goes on.. I think...

Comment: @Alearner It's your post so I guess I stand corrected. To me, asking what topology I am using in an analysis class is like which asking which field I am using in an arithmetic class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, it is correct.

Actually, the set in countable, so its interior is empty (why ?).

**Edit :** if you consider the set as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual topology on $\mathbb{Q}$, then $0$ is still not in the interior. Indeed, for all $N$, you have
$$ \frac{1}{N+1} < \frac{2N+1}{2N(N+1)} < \frac{1}{N}$$
So the rational
$\frac{2N+1}{2N(N+1)}$ does not belong to your set. But the sequence $\left(\frac{2N+1}{2N(N+1)}\right)_{N \in \mathbb{N}}$ tends to $0$.

Comment: I edited some..

Comment: @Alearner So did I.

Comment: So, only the discrete topology, where $0$ can be interior, or some other interesting topology .

Comment: Many topologies work. Calling $A$ your set, the topology whose open sets are exactly $\emptyset$, $A$, and $\mathbb{R}$ is another example.

Comment: Okk,,,, thanks!